# Data is sending even if validation requirements are not valid, whats the best way to approach this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, axios, react-hooks

So I've set up a custom react hook form with a simple validation(the validation works), the data from the form is sent to my Gmail, but I receive emails on button submit even if the fields are empty, I've tried a few methods to fix this but nothing seems to work, code looks like this:

> **Form.js :**

```
import React from "react";
import useForm from "./useForm";
import validate from "./validate";


const Form = () => {
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors } = useForm(
        submit,
        validate
    );
   

    function submit() {
        alert("Submitted Succesfully");
    }

    return (
        <div>
           
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                <div className="inputField">
                    <input className={`${errors.email && "inputError"}`} name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email *" value={values.email} onChange={handleChange} />
                    {errors.email && <p className="error">{errors.email}</p>}
                </div>
                <div className="inputField">
                    <input className={`${errors.email && "inputError"}`} name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name *" value={values.name} onChange={handleChange} />
                    {errors.email && <p className="error">{errors.name}</p>}
                </div>
                <div className="inputField">
                    <input className={`${errors.email && "inputError"}`} name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject *" value={values.subject} onChange={handleChange} />
                    {errors.email && <p className="error">{errors.subject}</p>}
                </div>
                <div className="inputField">
                    <p className="reqTxt"> * = Required</p>
                    <textarea className={`${errors.email && "inputError"}`} name="description" placeholder="Type your message here *" value={values.description} onChange={handleChange} rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
                    {errors.email && <p className="error">{errors.description}</p>}
                </div>


                <button className="btn" type="submit">Send message</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

> **useForm.js :**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: '', name: '', subject: '', description: '' })
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  

  const handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
  

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate(values));
    setIsSubmitting(true);

    const {email,name,subject,description} = values;
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/sendme', {
            
            email,
            name,
            subject,
            text: description
        })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
      callback();
    }
  }, [callback,isSubmitting,errors]);

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

> **validate.js :**

```
export default function validate(values) {
    let errors = {};
    if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = "Email is required";
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = "Email address is invalid, ex: your@email.com";
    }
    if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = "Please type in your name.";
    }
    if (!values.subject) {
        errors.subject = "Please don't leave the subject field empty.";
    }
    if (values.description.length < 20) {
        errors.description = "Your message needs to be more than 20 characters.";
    }
    return errors;
}
```

What is the best way to approach this (only send the data after the form validation = true or something)? I'd also like to know how to display a "success" message after the form is submitted successfully.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me an advice concerning this or can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `useForm` hook (`handleSubmit` method) you don't stop the method if there are any errors. You should return from the function if there are errors.

Something like

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const errors = validate(values);

    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
       setErrors(errors);
       return;
    }

    setIsSubmitting(true);

    const {email,name,subject,description} = values;
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/sendme', {
            
            email,
            name,
            subject,
            text: description
        })
  };
```